# Mac OS X (Lion) - logout/restart interrupted since application won't close

Tags: osx-lion

So. After upgrading I'm finally able to keep my applications between reboots - in theory at least.

Often the shutdown sequence is terminated by os x since it is tire of waiting for some application to close down. Usually the last one, which has shut down a few seconds after the shut down was terminated.

Is there any way to make os x wait, say, 120 seconds, instead of whatever the default wait time is?

(This is my first time posting here - please be gentle :)